# Not enough space on local standard disk in VMWare Player for Linux

Tags: vmware

Hi askubuntu community,

I'm completely new to virtual machines and Linux. And I have no clue about the terminologies and concepts.

A bit of my background, I studied electrical engineering technology: automation and instrumentation. I'm comfortable navigating through a basic PC on Windows OS, but I guess I'm just a casual. Currently, I'm using a Surface Pro and I mainly use the machine to browse sites like Quora, learn on platforms like Khan Academy and LinkedIn Learning.

I just tried a quick search on DuckDuckGo, but I don't think I could find this specific item.

Back to my problem, I am trying to learn more about information technology and information security. I was in the middle of this tutorial for SANS Cyber Aces: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=970&v=GNScr5bRG70&feature=emb_logo

I am stuck around the timestamp of 15:55. I encounter the issue of not having enough available space to install CentOS Linux onto my virtual machine.

I have attached a .PNG for reference down below.

From what I can make of it, I'm on a virtual space (VMWare) and I'm trying to install an OS (Linux, specifically: CentOS?) onto it, but not enough hardware available? But I don't understand where the hardware is coming from or why I can't use my Surface Pro's (which would be the host in this case)?

If someone can help me navigate through this installation and with understanding the concepts, I would greatly appreciate it!

[Snipped image of Installer: not enough space available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F6lE.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the disc space to 0.1 from 20GB, it should work. I had the same error but this resolved it.